Jquery email validation on progressive form
I'm working with a progressive form and seeking assistance in integrating email validation upon clicking the next button.
Presently, the form proceeds to the subsequent section regardless of whether an email address is entered in the field.
Looking forward to any help. Thanks in advance.
Here is the JS code
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    
    // click on next button
    jQuery('.msform-next-btn').click(function() {
        var parentFieldset = jQuery(this).parents('.msforms-fieldset');
        var currentActiveStep = jQuery(this).parents('.msform').find('.msform-steps .active');
        var next = jQuery(this);
        var nextmsformsStep = true;
        parentFieldset.find('.msforms-required').each(function(){
            


            var thisValue = jQuery(this).val();

            if( thisValue == "") {
                jQuery(this).siblings(".msforms-form-error").slideDown();
                nextmsformsStep = false;
            }
            else {
                jQuery(this).siblings(".msforms-form-error").slideUp();
            }
        });
        if( nextmsformsStep) {
            next.parents('.msforms-fieldset').removeClass("show","400");
            currentActiveStep.removeClass('active').addClass('activated').next().addClass('active',"400");
            next.parents('.msforms-fieldset').next('.msforms-fieldset').addClass("show","400");
            jQuery(document).find('.msforms-fieldset').each(function(){
                if(jQuery(this).hasClass('show')){
                    var formAtrr = jQuery(this).attr('data-tab-content');
                    jQuery(document).find('.msform-steps .msform-step-item').each(function(){
                        if(jQuery(this).attr('data-attr') == formAtrr){
                            jQuery(this).addClass('active');
                            var innerWidth = jQuery(this).innerWidth();
                            var position = jQuery(this).position();
                            jQuery(document).find('.msform-step-move').css({"left": position.left, "width": innerWidth});
                        }else{
                            jQuery(this).removeClass('active');
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
 
  

JSFIDDLE

Please click [edit], then the button marked [<>] and create a [mcve] HERE instead

@mplungjan  same question asked previously: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78353524/jquery-email-validation-on-progressive-form
